# Database hashing entry

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I've been trying to register a user into my database but my hashing of the string value seems to cause issues within the code.

```
public boolean insert(UserDTO user) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    boolean insertOK = false;
    String password;

    if (user.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword1())) {
        try {
            password = user.getPassword();
            byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
                            .digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             password = (Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash)); 

            user.setPassword(password);

            System.out.println(password);
            Connection conn = DbManager.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users (Id, Name, Username, Password, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Postcode, isAdmin) values (USER_SEQ.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)");           
            stmt.setString(1, user.getName());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getUsername());
            stmt.setString(3, password);
            stmt.setString(4, user.getAddressLine1());
            stmt.setString(5, user.getAddressLine2());
            stmt.setString(6, user.getCity());
            stmt.setString(7, user.getState());
            stmt.setString(8, user.getZipCode());
```

Passing in the password variable here as the hashed value is causing no entry to the database, however if I just put the unhashed string (user.getPassword) into the set string then an entry to the db is made.

Comment: *if i just put the unhashed string (user.getPassword) into the set string then an entry to the db is made.* This means there is an exception when you pass the hash. Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: where do I find this? @BackSlash

Comment: Print it inside the `catch` block using `yourException.printStackTrace()`, it will be logged in the console output.

Comment: It just tells me " groceryShop was successfully deployed in 1,755 milliseconds." but nothing about the stack trace